# How to convert radians to cosine in R

Tags: r

I want to convert my `radians` result into `cosines` because I will apply it to another algorithm and that algorithm does not recognize 0 equal to 360. When we input the number by degrees or radians, 0 degrees and 360 degrees are the same, but in the number, it cannot be the same. This is the reason to apply the triangle function.

This is what the sample looks like:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 6
   trip_id radian_1 radian_2 radian_3 radian_4 radian_5
     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
 1       1   -2.00     0.454    0.498    0.506   0.771 
 2       2   -0.523   -1.81    -2.63    -1.39    1.51  
 3       3   -3.04    -2.84     0.505    0.496   0.584 
 4       4    1.89     0.693    1.88    -1.58   -1.68  
 5       5    2.87     3.02     3.00    -2.71   -2.63  
 6       6    0.518    0.502    0.413    0.413  -0.0999
 7       7   -2.65    -2.65    -2.44    -1.53   -0.706 
 8   25854    0.642   -0.128    2.18     2.18   -0.109 
 9   25855    0.666    0.140    0.140    0.140   0.140 
10   25856   -1.16    -1.19     1.95     1.50   -0.0355
```

```
 data <- structure(list(trip_id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 25854, 25855,25856), radian_1 = c(-2.00436862096002, -0.523022409859805, -3.04422264927432,1.89439695729078, 2.86720821007505, 0.517940805671334, -2.65207596882566,0.64169854680564, 0.666322090631571, -1.16230390219715), radian_2 = c(0.454149332839053,-1.81438355628885, -2.83939683010968, 0.693317701570055, 3.01584249910548,0.502132823237947, -2.6453969953479, -0.128240831723981, 0.139736495379355,-1.18697841176111), radian_3 = c(0.498168941811998, -2.62713532396063,0.504505498915584, 1.88146033433837, 2.99585540355206, 0.413175854687464,-2.44007490822193, 2.17668778028128, 0.139736495379355, 1.94996861473123), radian_4 = c(0.506229172893869, -1.39185279873572, 0.496445628401911,-1.57718880002434, -2.7139691221202, 0.413175854687464, -1.53154648742157,2.17668778028128, 0.139736495379355, 1.50049341492273), radian_5 = c(0.77059331109462,1.505461455139, 0.583742590425588, -1.68323700322822, -2.63340912766466,-0.0998526552802892, -0.705591471540399, -0.109045967540331,0.139736495379355, -0.0354938975029716)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

So, my expected result should have columns name kind like this;

```
# A tibble: 10 x 6
   trip_id    cos_1    cos_2    cos_3    cos_4    cos_5
     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with `mutate` + `rename_with` in `dplyr`:

```
data %>%
    mutate(across(starts_with('radian_'), cos)) %>%
    rename_with(~sub('radian', 'cos', .x), starts_with('radian_'))

# # A tibble: 10 x 6
#    trip_id  cos_1  cos_2  cos_3    cos_4   cos_5
#      <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>
#  1       1 -0.420  0.899  0.878  0.875    0.717 
#  2       2  0.866 -0.241 -0.871  0.178    0.0653
#  3       3 -0.995 -0.955  0.875  0.879    0.834 
#  4       4 -0.318  0.769 -0.306 -0.00639 -0.112 
#  5       5 -0.963 -0.992 -0.989 -0.910   -0.874 
#  6       6  0.869  0.877  0.916  0.916    0.995 
#  7       7 -0.883 -0.879 -0.764  0.0392   0.761 
#  8   25854  0.801  0.992 -0.569 -0.569    0.994 
#  9   25855  0.786  0.990  0.990  0.990    0.990
# 10   25856  0.397  0.374 -0.370  0.0702   0.999
```

Comment: Thank you. Would you please explain: How do you get the cos of -0.420 in `cos_1`  first row. cos(-2) is 0.999.. Does the `cos`  function in R calculates cos directly from the radiant?? I thought we need the degree?

Comment: @TarJae `cos(-2)` is -0.42, while `cos(-2 * pi)` (or equivalently, `cospi(-2)`) is 1 in R. I treat the radian_* as radian values, i.e, no need to multiply by pi.

Answer (score 1):

Do it in a one-liner.

```
cbind(data[1], setNames(cos(data[-1]), gsub('radian', 'cos', names(data[-1]))))
#    trip_id      cos_1      cos_2      cos_3       cos_4      cos_5
# 1        1 -0.4201152  0.8986345  0.8784589  0.87457913  0.7174975
# 2        2  0.8663134 -0.2411855 -0.8705599  0.17799007  0.0652884
# 3        3 -0.9952633 -0.9546853  0.8754136  0.87928107  0.8344058
# 4        4 -0.3179824  0.7691299 -0.3056909 -0.00639243 -0.1122039
# 5        5 -0.9625922 -0.9921039 -0.9893991 -0.90995386 -0.8736298
# 6        6  0.8688405  0.8765580  0.9158503  0.91585027  0.9950189
# 7        7 -0.8825602 -0.8794001 -0.7638635  0.03923976  0.7612281
# 8    25854  0.8010802  0.9917884 -0.5694951 -0.56949507  0.9940604
# 9    25855  0.7861003  0.9902527  0.9902527  0.99025273  0.9902527
# 10   25856  0.3972262  0.3744633 -0.3701517  0.07024501  0.9993702
```